# Measuring signal shorter than instrument response function

Tags: experimental-physics, error-analysis, signal-processing, instrument

If one has a well-defined instrument response function (IRF) of some known full-width half maximum (FWHM), and they are measuring a signal that is shorter (but the shape is known), is it possible to resolve the duration of the signal? Furthermore, what is the resulting convolution of the IRF and the signal? I would imagine it to be the length of the IRF if not a bit longer due to the convolution.

Comment: What is FWHM? …

Comment: Full-width half maximum. Question has been modified to clarify.

Comment: Get a better quality instrument.